# Projectile only sees project related to current buffer, if the buffer belongs to a project

Tags: helm, projectile, project

I have two projects opened in my Emacs. Both are git repos and have `.projectile` files in their directories.

Relevant lines in my init.el

```
(projectile-global-mode 1)
(helm-mode)
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
(helm-projectile-on)
```

Problem:
`projectile-switch-project` (`C-c p p`) only shows a list containing the project related to current buffer. If I switch buffer to a file from the second project, the list contains just the second project. If I switch to a buffer not related to any project the list is empty.

When I disable Helm, then running `C-c p p` results in "There are no known projects" info in the minibuffer. Which is strange, because I see `Projectile[projectdirname]` in the modeline and for example `C-c p f` runs `projectile-find-project-file` as expected and lists the files from the current project.

I've tried `projectile-invalidate-cache` and `projectile-cleanup-known-projects` without success. Is there a trick (or an obvious step I have overlooked) to make projectile aware of opened projects?

platform: Windows7, Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) and GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601), Projectile 20150108.957 from Elpa.

Comment: Disregard my previous comments, `projectile-enable-caching t` is already the default on Windows. Maybe check your `~/.emacs.d/projectile.cache` file to see if your projects are there and caching correctly.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug now. If you use Dired to navigate and go back, you will lose your project name in the list as soon as you move outside of that project with Dired. Until when you actually open a file in that project, the project won't be added to project list. It is because `projectile-cache-files-find-file-hook` is only added to `find-file-hook` and `projectile-find-dir` hook.

Comment: I haven't used Dired, `projectile.cache` seems to look fine, but I've found a `projectile-bookmarks.eld` file in `~/.emacs.d/` and there was just a single entry. I've added paths to both of my projects there and I can switch between them using `C-c p p` (still doesn't work every time, but it's a progress).

Comment: Any updates here? I've just started to use helm-projectile, and I see the same behaviour. I don't have a projectile-bookmards.eld file, otherwise it seems to be the identical issue.

Comment: Seems my problems was related to helm-buffers-match-function not being defined. I aliased it to belm-buffers-list--match-fn and then it works. Something is buggy though...

Comment: Even though `projectile-enable-caching` may not have been @pawel's problem, it helped me - so thanks @nanny. Might be worth posting as an answer.